# How to load Syntax Highlighter on pages which contains pre tag ?

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

i am a Blogger and sometime's i need to demonstrate codes on my blog, so i used a Syntax Highlighter by Alex Gorbatchev. But the problem is that the files loads in each and every page of my Blog and that makes the blog load slow.

I have got codes on some pages only so i want a way to load the SyntaxHighlighter files only on pages having  tag. If there is any way to do it please help me out.

I searched StackOverflow for this question but didn't found any thread which can answer me.

Comment: Can you load js from the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery and requirejs already, you could do something like:

```
var preElements = $('.pre');
if (preElements.length > 0)
{
    //load the JS
    require(['shCore.js', 'shBrushJScript.js'], function (){
      //now apply it
      SyntaxHighlighter.all()
    });
}
```

Be careful that your logic doesn't somehow double apply to the same s.